# is estimated OR was estimated

Tags: tense, past-tense

It **IS/WAS** estimated that people consumed a lot of bottled water in 2015.

In the sentence above, **is** and **was** both are possible? Then how the nuance is different?
If there is no difference,  which is more natural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "nuisance" in this context.

> It was estimated that people consumed a lot of bottled water in 2015.

This means that the estimation/study was carried out at some point in the past.

---

> It is estimated that people consumed a lot of bottled water in 2015.

This refers to the *current* estimate. It is possible that the current estimate is different from the past estimate.

Comment: Ah, then if the research is done currently, then "is estimated "will be used, right?